# How to add transition on vanila javascript?(without jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

when i click nav2, it doesnt work 'transition'.
how to control transition on "javascript"?
and when i use 'display:flex' if i change some div`s height, all div`s height is changed which was "height:auto".
how can i control each other?

```js
const nav2 = document.querySelector(".nav2");
const menu = nav2.querySelector(".menu")

let checkOpen = false;

const menuBar = [
  {
    name:"AAAA",
    href:"#"
  },
  {
    name:"BBBB",
    href:"#"
  },
  {
    name:"CCCC",
    href:"#"
  },
  {
    name:"DDDD",
    href:"#"
  },
  {
    name:"EEEE",
    href:"#"
  }
]

function expand(){
  if(checkOpen === false){
    checkOpen = true;
    //nav2.style.height = "400px";
    const addAnchor = menuBar.map(a => {
      const _anchor = document.createElement("a");
      _anchor.innerText = a.name;
      _anchor.href = a.href;
      nav2.appendChild(_anchor)
    })
  } else {
    checkOpen = false;
    //nav2.style.height = "70px";
    for(var i = 0 ; i < menuBar.length ; i++){
      var anchor = nav2.querySelector("a:last-child")
      nav2.removeChild(anchor)
    }
  }
}

menu.addEventListener("click",expand);
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav1{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width:200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  margin: 20px;
}
.nav2{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width:200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  margin: 20px;
}
a{
  margin:15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}
.nav1:hover{
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="button2.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nav1">
    <a href="#">MENU</a>
    <a href="#">AAAA</a>
    <a href="#">BBBB</a>
    <a href="#">CCCC</a>
    <a href="#">DDDD</a>
    <a href="#">EEEE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav2">
    <a href="#" class="menu">MENU</a>
    
  </div>
  <script src="button2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

when i click nav2, it doesnt work 'transition'.
how to control transition on "javascript"?
and when i use 'display:flex' if i change some div`s height, all div`s height is changed which was "height:auto".
how can i control each other?

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes to your code, most notably:
CSS
`.nav2` has now a fixed height of 70px (no longer auto).
A new class has been added, `.expanded-menu`, to get `height: 400px` (same as `.nav1`)

JS
The class `.expanded-menu` is added/removed when the menu button is clicked.

```js
const nav2 = document.querySelector(".nav2");
const menu = nav2.querySelector(".menu")

let checkOpen = false;

const menuBar = [
  {
    name:"AAAA",
    href:"#"
  },
  {
    name:"BBBB",
    href:"#"
  },
  {
    name:"CCCC",
    href:"#"
  },
  {
    name:"DDDD",
    href:"#"
  },
  {
    name:"EEEE",
    href:"#"
  }
]

function expand(){
  if(checkOpen === false){
    checkOpen = true;
    nav2.classList.add("expanded-menu");
    const addAnchor = menuBar.map(a => {
      const _anchor = document.createElement("a");
      _anchor.innerText = a.name;
      _anchor.href = a.href;
      nav2.appendChild(_anchor)
    })
  } else {
    checkOpen = false;
    nav2.classList.remove("expanded-menu");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < menuBar.length ; i++){
      var anchor = nav2.querySelector("a:last-child")
      nav2.removeChild(anchor)
    }
  }
}

menu.addEventListener("click",expand);
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav1{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width:200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  margin: 20px;
}
.nav2{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width:200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
a{
  margin:15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}
.nav1:hover,
.expanded-menu{
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="button2.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nav1">
    <a href="#">MENU</a>
    <a href="#">AAAA</a>
    <a href="#">BBBB</a>
    <a href="#">CCCC</a>
    <a href="#">DDDD</a>
    <a href="#">EEEE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav2">
    <a href="#" class="menu">MENU</a>
    
  </div>
  <script src="button2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i try hide .nav2 the thxt is disapeared immediateldy.
but i want to that disapear slowly like opacity.